# How to insert vue.js computed data into form data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="uploadMeasurement(measure)">
      <input v-model="measure.length">
      <input v-model="measure.width">
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          measure: this.createFreshMeasure(),
        };
      },
      computed: {
        sqftTotal: function() {
          return this.length * this.width;
        }
      },
      methods: {
        uploadMeasurement(measure) {
          MeasurementService.uploadMeasurement(measure)
            .then(...);

              this.measure = this.createFreshMeasure();
            })
            .catch(error => {
              this.error = error.response.data.error;
            });
        },
        createFreshMeasure() {
          return {
            length: this.length,
            width: this.width,
            sqftTotal: this.sqftTotal

          };
        }
</script>
```

On submit, I'd like to calculate a square footage value using the values placed into the length and width inputs and send all three into the Mongo database.

The database is storing a value for sqftTotal when I send a hard-coded value directly over Postman, so it's capable of doing it, but this Vue form isn't accomplishing that task.

Comment: How are you creating a "fresh measure" as it stands?

Comment: Honestly, it feels like you're using a sledgehammer to drive a small nail. Any reason you don't just want to add length + width and send that to the DB instead of using a computed value?

Comment: The actual component I'm creating is a bit more complicated than this, but you may still be right, Arc. Problem is, when I placed "length * width" into the fresh function in any variation it did not send. 

Matt, the fresh data function is called by the uploading function.

Comment: @Arc what if the sqft needs to be displayed in the GUI? Computed props were built for scenarios just like this.. It is most definitely using the correct tool for the job. Besides, why not just compute the sqft on the client, vs use your servers resources =P

Comment: @connorontheweb do you not want to use values (length, width) that are currently in the inputs? Running the "fresh data function" on submit would generate different values than what is currently shown in the GUI...

Comment: I don't need the square footage to display reactively. When a new object is added, the space above the contact form will load the current array of objects. I just need that computation to happen and send to the database.

Comment: See my answer below... run the snippet and hit Submit...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be something like this.. I have commented different options within the code to help explain things..

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  template: `
  <div>
    <form ref="form">
      <!--<input v-model="measure.length">
      <input v-model="measure.width">-->
      <input v-model="length">
      <input v-model="width">
    </form>
    <button @click.prevent="uploadMeasurement">Submit</button>
  </div>
  `,
  data: {
    //measure: ""
    length: "",
    width: "",
  },
  computed: {
    sqftTotal: function() {
      //return this.measure.length * this.measure.width;
      return this.length * this.width;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uploadMeasurement() {
      /** This is where you would POST the data **/
      
      // You can either submit the form:
      // -NOTE: '...$refs.form...' below must match the ref
      //        you assign to the <form ref="form"> element.

      // this.$refs.form.$el.submit();

      // ~ OR ~

      // manually POST via fetch, etc:

      // fetch('/url/to/post/to', {
      //   method: 'POST',
      //   body: JSON.stringify({
      //     length: this.measure.length,
      //     width: this.measure.width,
      //     sqftTotal: this.sqftTotal
      //   })
      // })
      
      alert(JSON.stringify({
        //length: this.measure.length, 
        //width: this.measure.width, 
        length: this.length,
        width: this.width,
        sqftTotal: this.sqftTotal
      }));
    },
    createFreshMeasure() {
      this.length = 10;
      this.width = 5;
      //return {
      //  length: 10,
      //  width: 5
      //};
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.createFreshMeasure();
  //this.measure = this.createFreshMeasure();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: The tough thing here is that I'm within the this.measure scope while inside the fresh function. Inside that function it's this.length, this.width, etc. So maybe I need to pass that computation into this limited scope somehow.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that "*you're within the this.measure scope while inside the fresh function*"?  Why does that matter?

Comment: I'm calling this.length, this.width, etc; which I assume in the greater scope means this.measure.length...

Comment: Huh? Now I am just really confused.. where is `deck` coming from?

Comment: I find it strange that this.sqftTotal isn't working though. this.id is working, and that value is a prop passed from the view into the component and makes sense that this.id would work, yet this.sqftTotal does not.

Comment: Sorry, the actual project is using deck in place of measure. I changed it for this question. The mongo documents I'm adding are deck data tied to(inside) a project mongo document.

Comment: Bro what are you talking about? In your code example, there are no such properties as `id` or `deck`....

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Are you pulling data from Mongo that you want to display in the browser? Or are you taking data someone entered in inputs and posting it to Mongo?

Comment: Here's how it goes in the real life example. User creates a "project," then creates a number of "deck"s (deck measurements) tied to that project. It's for a construction company

Comment: Decks belong to Project, so the id is the Project id passed in as a prop to create that relationship.

Comment: Now that I am not sure about - you'll need to provide a more detailed example within your question if you want help with all of that... As far as being able to use a computed property to determine sqft, and a way to submit/POST that data, my answer provides that.

Comment: I appreciate your input here, I'll need to find a more clear way to illustrate what I'm talking about.

Comment: Got it, removed the 'measure' argument from the uploadMeasurement method, declared 'measure' before the service call and declared 'measure.sqftTotal = this.sqftTotal' underneath.

Comment: Thats literally exactly what I was doing.. Instead of `this.length` (and width) you were using `this.measure.length` (and width)...... I showed this in my answer (under the `uploadMeasurement()` method)... look how I am `alert`ing the data..... I just made the necessary changes to my example to make it exactly what you were looking for... I only commented out the old code so you can understand and visualize the difference.. Instead of using a `measurement` object to store `length` and `width` you're just storing them both directly as `data`.. there is no change to the logic whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

```
  methods: {
    uploadMeasurement() {
      let measure = this.measure;
      measure.sqftTotal = this.sqftTotal;
      MeasurementService.uploadMeasurement(measure)
      ...
```

Got it, thanks to everyone for your input. Had to remove the argument from the method and declare it before the service call.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend cleaning up your code like below, as Vue often has issues when using object properties as a model like that

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="uploadMeasurement()">
      <input v-model="length">
      <input v-model="width">
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          length: null,
          width: null,
        };
      },
      computed: {
        sqftTotal: function() {
          return this.length * this.width;
        }
      },
      methods: {
        uploadMeasurement() {
          MeasurementService.uploadMeasurement({
              length: this.length,
              width: this.width,
              sqftTotal: this.sqftTotal
            })
            .then(() => {
              console.log('save success!');
            })
            .catch(error => {
              this.error = error.response.data.error;
            });
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Code style does not answer OP's question?

Comment: What do you mean @MattOestreich, I only used his code and removed duplicate logic? OP asked about posting a computed value, and that is exactly what would happen with my example

Comment: How is the data even getting submitted?? There is no event/action that actually submits the form... Using `this.length` and `this.width` versus `this.measure.length` and `this.measure.width` is 100% opinion based, and formatting related. Formatting properties like that does not resolve OP's issue at all..

Comment: It's being passed to the measurement service as an object in his example above. Are you sure you're aware of what is happening in his/my logic. You've added a hidden field, which is one approach yet totally unnecessary given how Vue works...

Comment: I suppose it would submit on pressing 'enter'... I have not added a hidden field anywhere in my answer... please, elaborate on how this non-existent hidden field is not necessary because 'how Vue works'.. In what way does Vue work which deems my solution unnecessary. Are you sure you understand what's going on?

Comment: My apologies, tho a hidden field would be more appropriate, you've added a disabled input field, which is still unnecessary given he's passing an object to his service, which can include any values, not just DOM input values.. @MattOestreich this speaks to the issue of using object properties as your model https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Does that mean all I have to do is remove one input and you'll upvote my answer??? Because, ya know, that suddenly makes it a "hidden field"...

Comment: Still waiting for your explanation on "*...which is one approach yet totally unnecessary given how Vue works...*" - In what way does Vue work that makes it unnecessary?